Determine effective password character in a WinForms .NET app
I have a WinForms control in which I determine the system password character using code like this:
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
char passwordChar = (char)NativeMethods.SendMessage(textBox.Handle,
    NativeMethods.EM_GETPASSWORDCHAR, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
textBox.Dispose();

This code snippet is called in the control's constructor. One of my customers reported an issue with this part of code after running heavy unit tests. The most common error message was "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Error creating window handle." and it is related to the CreateHandle() method.
As I understand, many tests running in parallel simply exhaust the available pool of API resources. Is there any other way to determine the system password character in a WinForms app in .NET to avoid this issue?

There a lots of what you say that ring bells like "available pool of API resources" (what is this exactly) or "running in parallel" (that cannot work when a single thread is allowed to do work, like with UI apps). The problem is probably not with this code (using an legit/official Windows API), from what you say, it's somewhere else, how you do things (which we cannot see), and maybe how this other code does exhaust some resource (not being able to create a window is a big problem) in some way.

Can't you simply write char passwordChar = textBox.PasswordChar? -- This code is called in the ctor of what? -- Your TextBox has no Parent and is not visible, so a parking window is used (NativeWindow). When you set .UseSystemPasswordChar = true;, the Control needs to be recreated (in case it has already a handle). What kind of heavy unit tests (not integration) are performed in such a GUI that end up exhausting the handles available to a Process? If that's the case, and it's not simply a race condition

@Jimi, can you explain the problems we may have with this 'parking window' and race conditions in this context?

Well, for example the Parking windows are limited in number, given that non top-level Controls usually have a Parent, so accessing the windows' container follows the borrowing schema. ~Like borrowing Threads from the ThreadPool, Connections from the ConnectionPool, etc. A parking window is assigned while processing CreateHandle() - You should be more specific in relation to the context of the operations (as before: the Constructor of what? What tests are conducted? Is this actually a GUI?), then the issue may become more clear

Even if it may seem silly, could you try to add _ = textBox.Handle; textBox.CreateControl(); (the latter does almost nothing here, but takes some time) before char passwordChar = textBox.PasswordChar; (PInvoking manually is useless here, reading that property does the same thing)? If it's a race condition related to the deferred creation of the handle, you might see a difference (as mentioned, details are missing)
